# Android studio: Exception raised during rendering: action_bar on API 22 after switching to a lower version.

Tags: android, android-studio

I switched my project to API 15 for testing purposes and had some errors, namely `Chould't resolve resource @style/widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode (2 similar errors not shown)` and when i switch back I get `Exception raised during rendering: action_bar` even after a restart, clean... Can someone please help.

P.S. I heard you need to use the toolbar from now on but I can't find any material on it.

Comment: Have you updated gradle with any external library ?

Comment: I got the same error.they are saying this cause some java compilation error.i removed the newly added gradle dependency path,synced the gradle and once again added the dependency path then rebuild the project.gradle automatically fetched and added the library when i rebuild.all is well now.